# error when try install byebug

Tags: ruby, rubygems, byebug

I get the error when I try to install byebug.
What's the reason for this?

```
sudo gem install byebug -v '10.0.1'
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing byebug:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-10.0.1/ext/byebug
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180326-12662-69j4pj.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-10.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.3.0/byebug-10.0.1/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error `mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h` is telling you it can't find the header file needed to build the gem.

Also, why are you installing with `sudo` ?  What system are you on? Are you using a version manager `rvm` or `rbenv` ?   I recommend https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Try to install with system libraries

```
gem install byebug -v '10.0.1' --use-system-libraries
```

If that doesn't work please run the following commands and post their output:

```
which ruby
ruby -v
gem -v
echo "${PATH//:/\n}" #may not work if your not on an *nix system
```

UPDATE:

Go to root of the project.  Pick a ruby version but it looks like the ruby is pointing to a system ruby, not an rvm version.  Try install a new ruby:

```
rvm install 2.4.1
rvm use 2.4.1
gem install byebug
```

If you have a Gemfile in your project and if it has `ruby -v` make sure it matches your version you set with rvm and add `gem 'byebug'` to your Gemfile then run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Hi there, I'm using Ubuntu. I get the error when I typed: gem install byebug -v '10.0.1' --use-system-libraries
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --use-system-libraries

Comment: which ruby -> /usr/bin/ruby
ruby -v -> ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [i386-linux-gnu]
gem -v -> 2.7.6
echo "${PATH//:/\n}" -> /usr/local/sbinn/usr/local/binn/usr/sbinn/usr/binn/sbinn/binn/usr/gamesn/usr/local/gamesn/snap/binn/home/yuri/.rvm/binn/home/yuri/.rvm/bin

Comment: rvm -v ---> rvm 1.29.3 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]

Comment: What type of application?  Is there a Gemfile in your project root?

Comment: It worked out now. Greats. I think that was some updating that I done yesterday

Comment: Thank you so much for helping!